# Make the "List of Tables/Figures" an independent chapter in the appendix

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to make the "List of Tables" and "List of Figures" as two independent chapters in the appendix section as follow:

```
Appendix A: List of Figures
Fig. 1 --------
Fig. 2 --------

Appendix B: List of Tables
Tab. 1 --------
Tab. 2 --------
```

I have tried the following code but it does not work as expected

```
\appendix 
\begingroup
\chapter{List of tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\endgroup
%
\appendix 
\begingroup
\chapter{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\endgroup
```

Comment: The command `\appendix` does only one thing: changing the  chapter numbering to Roman after resering the counter to 0. But the list of ... are in standard LaTeX unencumbered chapter, so no hope in this way. Likely  patching them with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the minimal example I've come up with. I hope it helps. What you are searching for is **`\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of XX}`**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}       % for including graphics.
\usepackage{caption}        % For caption of Tables


\begin{document}
% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents        

\
\section{First Chapter}
It's me, Mario!

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
    \caption{Some Figure}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\captionof{table}{Some Table} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\appendix
%% List of Figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables   

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: example]

With `\clearpage` you could also insert blank pages between e.g. the chapter, the table of contents, the table of figures etc.

Comment: Thanks very much! Works as expected